# Dealing with a highly-popular invalid answer

Tags: discussion, answers

[This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108041/19365) to the [Output your programming language name](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name) challenge is invalid: it doesn't actually produce output, and arguably isn't even a program (at least, not in the language it claims to be written in).  Normally, this would be dealt with by downvoting the answer into oblivion.  However, the question got on the HNQ list, and to an outsider, it looks like a clever trick to get an extremely short program, making it the fourth-highest-voted answer.  How do we deal with this?